# How to check whether the fields are enabled and iterate 10 plus drop down fields to pass unique value in each dropdown

Tags: java, list, selenium, webdriver

Could you please help me to check 10 plus fields are enabled, if enabled then pass unique value into each drop down field.

Below is my code but please let me know how do I iterate to check the field is enabled and if enabled then pass unique value to each dropdown.

```
 WebElement fieldvalue1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@aria- 
    label='amendments?'])"));
                 fieldvalue1.sendKeys("Yes");
                 fieldvalue1.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
    WebElement fieldvalue2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@aria- 
    label='appropriateness as applicable?'])"));
             fieldvalue2.sendKeys("Yes");
                 fieldvalue2.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
    WebElement fieldvalue3 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@aria- 
    label='account statements deleted?'])"));
                 fieldvalue3.sendKeys("Yes");
                 fieldvalue3.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
    WebElement fieldvalue4 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@aria- 
    label='Statement recipient?'])"));
                 fieldvalue4.sendKeys("Yes");
                 fieldvalue4.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
    WebElement fieldvalue5 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@aria- 
    label='Fee agreement?'])"));
                 fieldvalue5.sendKeys("Yes");
                 fieldvalue5.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
    WebElement fieldvalue6 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@aria- 
    label='Properly executed?'])"));
                 fieldvalue6.sendKeys("Yes");
                 fieldvalue6.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
```

Comment: Please show HTML of one dropdown list and all  dropdown lists  have similar HTML code structure?

Answer (score 0):

You have to store all 10 drop down in a list of web element.

Something like this :

```
List<WebElement> dropDowns =   driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpathExpression));

for(WebElement dropDown : dropDowns){
           dropDown.click();
           dropDown.sendKeys(generateString().trim() + Keys.TAB);
          }
```

As per you **requirement** (pass **unique** value into each drop down field)

```
 public static String generateString() {
         String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
         return  uuid;
     }
```

HTH

Comment: Hi - I am able to accomplish using the above script, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Hi @Raj : Glad it worked for you ! You can mark this question as accepted, by clicking on check mark which is just under the down vote button. Thanks !